# Using JSONP with WCF and jQuery

Tags: ajax, wcf, rest, jquery

I have deployed my WCF service on test machine of client calling it from same client machine using my client HTML website I get response like this:

[image]

But when I deploy same components on production machine of our client response I am getting from WCF service is different like this:

[image]

I am working on ajax call for cross domain. I call rest service from my HTML website deployed on other machine. This is the error I can see on firebug because of this different output from WCF service:

[image]

This is code of my WCF method. It is simple method I have written only to see what is happening:

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string PingMe()
{
    return "No Domains";
}
```

What could be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there are different versions of the -NET framework running on the test and production server. The "d" was introduced some time ago, in .NET 3.5 if I am not mistaken, as a security feature to protect against some forms of XSS attacks.

You can read more about it in [this](http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/) article. [This article](http://encosia.com/jquery-1-5s-ajax-rewrite-and-asp-net-services-all-is-well/) from Dave Ward has a nice general purpose solution using a jQuery dataFilter.